# How to Create Load More With PHP and PDO

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, load

i want to create load more to my site, but when i try to click load more it just load 2 items.

my index.php

```
<div class="postList">
    <?php
    // Include the database configuration file
    include 'koneksi.php';

    // Get records from the database
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM master_post, posting WHERE master_post.master_post_name = posting.master_post_name AND posting.sticky = 'Normal' ORDER BY posting.idpost DESC LIMIT 2");
    $query->execute();
    if($query->rowCount() > 0){
        while($row = $query->fetch()){ 
            $postID = $row['idpost'];
    ?>
    <div class="list_item"><?php echo $row['file_name']; ?></div>
    <?php } ?>
    <div class="show_more_main" id="show_more_main<?php echo $postID; ?>">
        <span id="<?php echo $postID; ?>" class="show_more" title="Load more posts">Show more</span>
        <span class="loding" style="display: none;"><span class="loding_txt">Loading...</span></span>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.show_more',function(){
        var ID = $(this).attr('id');
        $('.show_more').hide();
        $('.loding').show();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'ajax_more.php',
            data:'id='+ID,
            success:function(html){
                $('#show_more_main'+ID).remove();
                $('.postList').append(html);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

my ajax_more.php

```
if(!empty($_POST["id"])){

    // Include the database configuration file
    include 'koneksi.php';

    // Count all records except already displayed
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as num_rows FROM master_post, posting WHERE master_post.master_post_name = posting.master_post_name AND posting.sticky = 'Normal' AND posting.idpost < ".$_POST['id']." ORDER BY posting.idpost DESC");
    $row = $query->fetch();
    $totalRowCount = $row['num_rows'];

    $showLimit = 2;

    // Get records from the database
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM master_post, posting WHERE master_post.master_post_name = posting.master_post_name AND posting.sticky = 'Normal' AND posting.idpost < ".$_POST['id']." ORDER BY posting.idpost DESC LIMIT $showLimit");

    if($query->rowCount() > 0){
        while($row = $query->fetch()){
            $postID = $row['idpost'];
    ?>
        <div class="list_item"><?php echo $row['file_name']; ?></div>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php if($totalRowCount > $showLimit){ ?>
        <div class="show_more_main" id="show_more_main<?php echo $postID; ?>">
            <span id="<?php echo $postID; ?>" class="show_more" title="Load more posts">Show more</span>
            <span class="loding" style="display: none;"><span class="loding_txt">Loading...</span></span>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
<?php
    }
}
```

I'm not sure where the mistake is. im using tutorial from this site https://www.codexworld.com/load-more-data-using-jquery-ajax-php-from-database/

Comment: `LIMIT 2` in your query might have something to do with you only getting 2?

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!